# Change vtkActor bounds

Tags: 3d, vtk

[image: vtkActor bounds]

I have an actor(black line in picture) which when oriented parallel to x or y axis has the bounding box as I'd want it(seen in red in the picture). But when the actor is oriented with an angle, the bounding box grows and this causes a problem for me. The problem being having a different center of rotation when using vtkTrackballActor interactor. Is there a way that I can always have the bounding box be like when its parallel to x or y?